Is a compact Hausdorff group with finite homotopy type a Lie group
Suppose $G$ is a compact, Hausdorff topological group and $X$ a finite CW-complex and $X\to G$ a weak-equivalence. Does it follow that $G$ is a Lie group or could someone provide a counterexample.
In the case that $G$ is profinite, $G$ actually has to be finite by inspecting the number of connected compontents. I want to reduce to this case by arguing that $G=\varprojlim G_i$ for $G_i$ compact Lie groups and maybe one can show that the dimensions of the $G_i$ must stabilize.
